# How to access Go private repository using the Go Docker image in a multi-stage build?

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I have the following dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.16.3 as compile
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
# CGO_ENABLED for static linking library
RUN go env -w GOPRIVATE="github.com/<some_account>/*"; GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -ldflags "-X main.version=$1 -X main.build=`date -u +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S`" -o /app/server server.go

FROM scratch
#WORKDIR /
#FROM alpine:latest
#RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=compile /app/server .
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
CMD ["./server"]
```

This file is located with my Golang source codes and I run `docker build .` to build the executable as a docker image. But this code uses Go package from a private repo in GitHub. And during the first stage, it cannot access that private repo. In my RUN statement I attempt to set the Go Environment `GOPRIVATE`, but it doesn't work.

`ARG GOPRIVATE "github.com/<some_account>/*"` and `ENV GOPRIVATE "github.com/<some_account>/*"` also seem to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your build env access to the private repo. In your pre-stage Docker build, generate a`.netrc` file with an access token to your private repo:

```
# .netrc
## generate token with https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-oauth-token-for-command-line-usee
machine github.com login <token>
```

This should resolve your build issue.